# Python Selenium Webdriver - Dynamically change download directory

Tags: python, selenium

To explicitly define the download directory prior to defining the selenium webdriver we use the following code:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:/data/cline"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromePath = "path to chromedriver"

driver = selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path=chromePath, port=0,    chrome_options=chromeOptions, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None,   service_log_path=None)
```

I want to download a number of files, each to a different (newly created) directory. Is it possible to change the download directory after defining driver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change default download folder while webdriver is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896625/how-to-change-default-download-folder-while-webdriver-is-running)

Answer (score 3):

I have been unable to figure out how to do this and have used a work around.  Instead of changing the webDriver download directory on the fly, the below solution just moves the file that you download.

[ExperimentsWithCode Gave the Answer Here.  Below is part of his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896625/how-to-change-default-download-folder-while-webdriver-is-running)

```
def move_to_download_folder(downloadPath, newFileName, fileExtension):
    got_file = False   
    ## Grab current file name.
    while got_file = False:
        try: 
            currentFile = glob.glob(DOWNLOAD_PATH+"*"+fileExtension)
            got_file = True

        except:
            print "File has not finished downloading"
            time.sleep(20)

    ## Create new file name
    fileDestination = downloadPath+newFileName+fileExtension

    os.rename(currentFile, fileDestination)

    return
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this way to change download folder during webdriver running:

```py
driver.command_executor._commands['send_command'] = (
    'POST', '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
download_path = 'PATH/TO/MY/CURRENT/DESIRED'
params = {
    'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
    'params': { 'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_path }
}
driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

or:

```py
download_path = 'PATH/TO/MY/CURRENT/DESIRED'
params = { 'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_path }
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params['params'])
```

It won't change Chrome's default download location setting, but will save file to the new given folder (will create if not exists) in subsequent downloads.

Comment: Only first one works. Second method throws error ("params does not exists or smth")
Thank you for the first 

Answer (score -2):

```
driver.set_preference("download.default_directory", "path/")
```

Try this variant.

Comment: Tried this and got this error: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'set_preference'