# Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

**Scenario**: There is a requirement of downloading files from web hierarchy to local drive under same hierarchy.

Example Web Hierarchy:

```
Parent 1:  
  Child 1:  
    *File 1  
  Child 2:  
    *File 2
```

When downloading File 1, it should store in path 1 - "C:\....\Downloads\Parent 1\Child 1\"

When downloading File 2, it should store in path 2 - "C:\....\Downloads\Parent 1\Child 2\"

**Problem**:

When I keep "C:....\Downloads\Parent 1\Child 1\" download path in chrome webdriver while initializing webdriver first time in setUp() & download "File 1", it downloads in expected folder.
But when I set next "C:....\Downloads\Parent 1\Child 2\" download path in chrome webdriver for downloading File 2 in it, it opens another chrome browser because I am using another webdriver for setting path 2.

**Required Solution**:

I want to use existing webdriver to set different chrome download paths or any other workaround you can think of.

**Current Code**:

```
def setUp(self):  
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, option_with_path_1_set)

def test_downloadFiles(self):  
\*code to download first file\*  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, option_with_path_2_set)  
\*code to download second file\*  

def tearDown(self):  
browser.quit()
```

Please let me know if you require any additional information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't change it, but you can download file to some temp location, and then move downloaded file to a different location, see solution to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734399/python-selenium-webdriver-dynamically-change-download-directory

Answer (score 12):

When you configure an instance of a *ChromeDriver* through *ChromeOptions* to initiate a new *Chrome Browser* the configuration gets **baked** into the *chromedriver* executable which will persist for the lifetime of the *WebDriver* and remain **uneditable**.

Even if you are able to extract the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. **Session ID**, **Cookies** and other session attributes from the initiated *Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change those attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to call **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to **close** and **destroy** the *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to set selenium webdriver from headless mode to normal mode within the same session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721676/how-to-set-selenium-webdriver-from-headless-mode-to-normal-mode-within-the-same/54722252#54722252)
- [How do I make Chrome Headless after I login manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296228/how-do-i-make-chrome-headless-after-i-login-manually/53296911#53296911)